# How would the end of DST in the EU affect the Java8 time API

Tags: java-8, java-time

The new time api that was introduced with java 8 allows to conveniently work with timezones and takes care whether
a time within a specific timezone is currently in daylight savings time (DST) or not. Therefore specific rules are used.
Eg. In europe:

- DST starts on the last sunday of march
- DST ends on the last sunday of october

In the future these rules might change since the EU wants to [dismiss DST permanently](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-may-scrap-dst.html).
How would such a new regulation affect java's time library? Would such a change require every application 
that relies on correct datetimes to upgrade to a new java version? (In other words: would all applications that
still "need" to run on a java8 JRE work with wrong dates/times?)

Comment: You're able to update tz data ([HERE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tzupdater-readme-136440.html))